# Golang reflection slice shows up as struct

Tags: go, reflection

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

func someFunc( data interface{}, out interface{} ) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(out).Elem();
    fmt.Printf("Incoming type: %s\n",reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind())
    v.SetCap(reflect.ValueOf(data).Len())
}

func main() {
    expected := []int{1,2,3}

    jsonRaw, _ := json.Marshal(expected)
    var tmpData interface{}

    json.Unmarshal(jsonRaw, &tmpData)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",string(jsonRaw))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n",tmpData)

    result := []int{}
    var tmp interface{}
    tmp = result
    fmt.Printf("Outcoming type: %s\n",reflect.TypeOf(&tmp))
    someFunc(tmpData,&tmp)
}
```

I would like to operate on `v` parameter inside `someFunc` as if it were
a slice, i.e. "Incoming type"-debug message should output `slice`.
However, it outputs `struct`, as is shown [here](https://play.golang.org/p/YZxPmAtC0RW).
The ultimate goal is that I use reflection to analyze the `data`-parameter's contents and recover everything into `out`, but for now I would like to
know how to make sure the correct type of `v` is detected,
so that I can use it as a slice.

EDIT: It appears to be impossible (as of 2013 at least): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/bldM9tIL-JM
to set the size of a slice for stuff discovered at runtime.
One of the authors says something to the effect that "you have to be able
to sort the elements, i.e. implement `Less()`" for the values...

EDIT: In any case, I did try to use `MakeSlice` in this [Playgound link](https://play.golang.org/p/lRV-hSY2xYc),
and it says `reflect.MakeSlice of non-slice type`

EDIT: I apologize and thank you all for your comments.
What I ended up doing is the following (after an illuminating read of the source code of MakeSlice):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

func someFunc( data interface{}, out interface{} ) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(out).Elem();
    fmt.Printf("Incoming type: %s\n",v.Kind())
    //v.SetCap(reflect.ValueOf(data).Len()) <-- doesn't work
    n := reflect.ValueOf(data).Len()
    s := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf(data),n,n)
    fmt.Printf("Len= %d\n",s.Len())
}

func main() {
    expected := []int{1,2,3}

    jsonRaw, _ := json.Marshal(expected)
    var tmpData interface{}

    json.Unmarshal(jsonRaw, &tmpData)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",string(jsonRaw))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n",tmpData)

    result := []int{}
    someFunc(tmpData,&result)
}
```

Comment: In a more isolated example, it worked. SE questions help you in a way that it forces to write self-contained MWEs.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, please see my edit. I think I need to find another way.

Comment: You recently asked and deleted two questions. I wrote an answer to one of the questions with working code. You deleted the question before I could submit the answer. I will not engage further for fear of you deleting the question out from under me.

Comment: @Ilonpilaaja Given a slice type, it was possible to make slice with specified size and capacity using reflect since Go 1.  The functionality to make a slice given the element type was added in Go 1.1.

Comment: If you have solved your own issue, you should post the solution *as an answer* instead of editing the question to include the solution. Or, if you think it would not help others, delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is the following (after an illuminating read of the source code of MakeSlice):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

func someFunc( data interface{}, out interface{} ) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(out).Elem();
    fmt.Printf("Incoming type: %s\n",v.Kind())
    //v.SetCap(reflect.ValueOf(data).Len()) <-- doesn't work
    n := reflect.ValueOf(data).Len()
    s := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf(data),n,n)
    fmt.Printf("Len= %d\n",s.Len())
}

func main() {
    expected := []int{1,2,3}

    jsonRaw, _ := json.Marshal(expected)
    var tmpData interface{}

    json.Unmarshal(jsonRaw, &tmpData)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",string(jsonRaw))
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n",tmpData)

    result := []int{}
    someFunc(tmpData,&result)
}
```

It appears that there are convenience functions such as `SliceOf`, too.
the bottomline is that the first argument of `MakeSlice` is not the type
of the arguments that the slice holds, but the slice-type, e.g. `[]int` rather than `int`.